# Changing picture in javascript form on a click

Tags: javascript, html, exception, forms

In this code I get the following error:Exception... "Index or size is negative or greater than the allowed amount"  code: "1" nsresult: "0x80530001 (NS_ERROR_DOM_INDEX_SIZE_ERR)". What is causing this? Thanks

```
    function makecard(){ 
    var bodypaint = document.getElementById('minaj'); 
    var recipient = document.getElementById("recipient").value 
    var radioboxes = document.forms["cardform"].phrase.length 
    var i = document.getElementById("color").selectedIndex; 
    var z = document.getElementById("city").selectedIndex; 
    var tchatche= document.getElementById("color").options[i].text; 
    var malouba= document.getElementById("city").options[z].value; 

    for(c=0; c<radioboxes; c++){ 
        if( document.forms["cardform"].phrase[c].checked){ 
            var phrasevalue=document.forms["cardform"].phrase[c].value; 
            break; 
        } 
    } 
    if(document.getElementById("color").options[i].text === "White"){ 
        bodypaint.style.backgroundColor ="White" 
    } 
    if(document.getElementById("color").options[i].text === "Red"){ 
        bodypaint.style.background ="Red" 
    } 
    if(document.getElementById("color").options[i].text === "Blue"){ 
        bodypaint.style.backgroundColor ="Blue" 
    } 
    var selectedcity = document.forms["cardform"].city.value 
    var paragraph = document.createElement("div"); 
    paragraph.setAttribute("id","card") 
    document.body.appendChild(paragraph) 
    var picture = document.createElement("img") 
    picture.setAttribute("src", "") 
    paragraph.appendChild(picture) 
    paragraph.appendChild(document.createTextNode(phrasevalue + " from " + selectedcity + recipient)) 

    if(malouba== "Paris"){ 
        document.getElementById("picture").src = "paris.jpg" 
    } 


    if(malouba== "Venice"){ 
        document.getElementById("picture").src = "venice.jpg" 
    } 


    if(malouba== "Rome"){ 
        document.getElementById("picture").src = "rome.jpg" 
    } 
} 
document.getElementById("makeacard").onclick = makecard;
```

Answer (score 0):

It's highly likely that one of the statements is producing a array of 0 elements and then when you try to use it later it freaks out:

```
    var radioboxes = document.forms["cardform"].phrase.length
```

do a little console.log(radioboxes) on that and see if it comes back undefined or empty

Comment: Thanks for the response. i tried Your suggestion and that helped. But now in IE, when I try to change the background color it just flashes instead of changing it permanently.

Comment: You should probably post a new question for that :)

Comment: Ok well say I do get 0 from  select box selectedIndex property . Would it still freak out, even though arrays start at 0?

Comment: an array often starts @ 0, so the IE issue is likely something completely different...then again..it's IE